# Restricting browser autofill of addresses or any other fields which browser providing for autofill suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to restrict the suggestions provided by the browser(addresses) from development side using JavaScript.
My web application is on react so if I am able to restrict it from react side then also it is fine.
Can anyone please help me with the same.

Comment: Please add your sample code and also explain the behavior you are expecting in brief with one simple example. It will help more people to understand and help you with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autoComplete="off"` on `<input type="text" autoComplete='new-address' />`

Comment: I already tried the same. But not getting the result.

Comment: Try using `autoComplete="new-address"`

Comment: autoComplete="new-address" did the work.Thanks

Comment: I am still getting the issue if the field is related to credit card input or password input.